# Unable to create new list item in another list using Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, list-item

I am trying to create a list item in List 2, when List 1 form is submitted. But I'm getting below error

> The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more columns for the item require a different type of information".

I think the error is because of the `Path and Name` field. I tried various options listed in other posts, but no positive results.

**Update**

Here is the screenshot of the error and workflow.

[image]

Here the if part executes but the else part fails.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Check the field type are matching for the value you are trying to insert

Comment: Path and Name field is added automatically when I do a create item action. And I supplied the URL which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
https://your-path-to-list2/[%Current Item:Title%]

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx